# Using logback, lombok and Spring Boot 2.4 in combination efficiently

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, lombok

Lombok provides a [@Log annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/log) and supports (besides others) these logging frameworks:

- Commons Logging
- Slf4J
- Log4J
- ...

Logback is not on the list of supported logging frameworks but on the other hand Spring Boot uses logback as its default implementation (if my [source is correct](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging#2-log-levels))

How can I make use of lomboks annotation without having to add more logging frameworks or "converters" ?
Is using `@CustomLog` with `lombok.log.custom.declaration` my only option ?

Comment: [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) natively implements the [SLF4J API](http://www.slf4j.org/), so since it supports SLF4J, it supports Logback.

Comment: I thought logback ran behind the Slf4J API?  Is there another loback-specific API as well? - UPDATE: Ha.  Andreas and I think alike.

Comment: @CryptoFool Actually, I was quoting the Logback home page: *"Moreover, logback-classic **natively implements the SLF4J API** so that you can readily switch back and forth between logback and other logging frameworks such as log4j or java.util.logging (JUL)."*

Comment: @Andreas - right...gotcha.  I knew this because we use logback and yet our imports are all SLF4J.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot(2.4) `starter-logging` uses Logback by default which implements SLF4J APIs, so the simplest approach using logging with Lombok is adding `@Slf4j` on classes, and use `log` (Sl4j `Logger` class) to record your logging message directly.

```java
@Component //spring components
@Slf4j // from Lombok
class MyComponent{

    void foo(){
        log.info("test foo");
    }

}
```

Spring 5 internally introduced a new logging implementation. In the previous version, Spring is dependent on Apache Commons logging. Spring 5 added a new module `spring-jcl`, which removed the dependency `commons-logging` , but it still reuses the `Log` interface from `commons-logging` and provides a simple implementation to iterates the logger provider in classpaths and check the existence of the Slf4j, Log4j 2, etc. If it is found, this log will be delegated to the underlying logging framework. If none is found, it will use the fallback handling in the simple implementation of `Log` to handle logging. For more details, please have a look at [the source codes of LogAdapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jcl/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/LogAdapter.java#L50) in Spring JCL.

That means in a Spring Boot projct when adding `starter-logging`(by default used sfl4j/logback) and there is no other logging framework included, although you are using Lombok `@Log`(the Lombok will use Apache `commons-logging` `Log` interface), it will be delegated to the Slf4j provided by `starter-logging`.

To use Log4j2, excluded stater-logging from web/webflux starters and add starter-log4j2(optionally you can switch to use Lombok `@Log4j2`).

For Logback and Log4j2, Spring boot provides an extra **profile aware** config feature.
eg. `logback-spring.xml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs"/>

    <appended ...>
    //....
    <springProfile name="staging"> <!-- profile specific config -->
        <logger .../>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

Thus you can switch the detailed logging config at runtime according to the Spring profiles used, check [the logging section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging) of Spring boot docs.

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much just works. You add logback's config file (`logback-spring.xml`) to you classpath (e.g. `resources` folder) and then just use `@Log` in your classes to create a logger.

Comment: But which logging framework / facade will this use then ?

Comment: slf4j - as far as I can tell